# How to create a utf8 db with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I feel like this should be simple but i can't work out how to set the character set when making a db with "mysqladmin create".  I thought this would work

```
mysqladmin -u root db_name --character-set=utf8
```

leveraging this bit of the mysqladmin --help text:

-O, --set-variable=name 
                      Change the value of a variable. Please note that this
                      option is deprecated; you can set variables directly with
                      --variable-name=value.

i also tried this

```
mysqladmin -u root create db_name --default-character-set=utf8
```

In both cases, the db was created without complaint, but i don't think it's worked:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES like '%character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_connection | latin1                     | 
| character_set_database   | latin1                     | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | latin1                     | 
| character_set_server     | latin1                     | 
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | 
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

I can see that character_set_system is utf8, but should all of the latin1's above be showing utf8?

Grateful for any advice - max

Comment: BTW, i kind of fixed this by changing my mysql config to use utf8, following this blog post:http://boblet.tumblr.com/post/44164369/mysql-utf8   

So, new dbs have utf8.  But, i'd still like to know if i can set it when i create a db.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, the variables that you have displayed are the options of **your connection**, not the database. If you make a database dump, you will see, that everything is in place. For more options see **SET NAMES 'charset'** command in [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html).

Answer (score -1):

I'm coming back to answer my own question, since i just tried to do this with a more recent install of mysql and it didn't work:  i think the options have changed.

In mysql 5.5, which i have, the relevant config options (to make databases default to utf8 character set) are:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect = 'SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```